# How to Validate xHtml1.1 document offline in Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, xhtml, lxml, w3c-validation

I need to set a test method that validates whether the markup provided as a Python string is **valid xHtml1.1**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

As this will run on an internal CI, it has to be able to process without sending the content to any external service (I would not like to use online validator like https://validator.w3.org/ but get similar result).

What I have spotted on is https://lxml.de/validation.html#id1, which looks promising. The issue is that I am stuck on getting the valid DTD.

```
from lxml.etree import DTD
dtd = DTD(external_id = "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN")
```

This does not work for me :(

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DTDParseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c6bf8522a141> in <module>()
----> 1 dtd = DTD(external_id = "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN")

/tmp/tmp.dWRxTnmLqz/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so in lxml.etree.DTD.__init__()

DTDParseError: error parsing DTD
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `w3c-sgml-lib` package provides missing DTD, so after installing this `DTDParseError` is not raised any more:

```
 sudo apt install w3c-sgml-lib libxml2
```

As for now I am using Python2 code for *xHtml1.1* validation similar to the one below:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python2
 # vim: set fileencoding=utf-8 :
 #
 # This is an example for https://stackoverflow.com/q/51236003/388968
 #
 # Copyright 2018 (c) Sebastian Sawicki (0x52fb0d10)
 #  OPENPGP4FPR:5691BED8E6CA579830842DD85CB361E552FB0D10
 #
 # Licence: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/
 #

 from lxml.etree import DTD
 from lxml.etree import fromstring

 from six import string_types

 def isValidXHtml11(s):
  return isinstance(s, string_types) and
   s.startswith('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
   '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" ' +
   '"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">\n') and
   DTD(external_id = '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN').validate(
    fromstring(response.body)
   )
```

...anyway, this is open for any suggestions or improvements.